# Unix Grep for hardcoded passwords

Tags: unix, grep

So as a part of audit, I want to find out if the application has any hardcoded password. Currently I am using the following command.

```
 grep -irw "password" *
```

But I want it to match the following

```
password=ABC
password= ABC
password = ABC
any other combination including white spaces
```

How can that be done ?

So the intention is to

```
To match if there is a string starts with password, 0 or more spaces, =, 0 or more spaces, and then any 1 or more letters
```

Comment: What is your intention? To match if there is a string with `password`, 0 or more spaces, `=`, 0 or more spaces, and then any 1 or more letters?

Comment: Yes E xactly. Better if we match with 'pwd' and 'pass' as well.

Comment: Like `grep -irE '(password|pwd|pass)[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*[[:alpha:]]+' *`?

Comment: Could you please explain it in more detail?  I do not quite get what you really need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You should write this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most probably looking for

```
grep -irE '(password|pwd|pass)[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*[[:alpha:]]+' *
```

The regex is a POSIX ERE expression that matches

- `(password|pwd|pass)` - either `password` or `pwd` or `pass`
- `[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*` - a `=` enclosed with 0 or more whitespaces
- `[[:alpha:]]+` - 1 or more letters.

To output matches, add `-o` option to `grep`.